# Changing WordPress media location and upload path to sub-domain not working

Tags: uploads

I am trying to change the location of all WordPress media to a subdomain located above the site root ie, above public_html. I updated the `wp-config.php` settings to:

`define('UPLOADS', 'https://cdn.mysite.com/media');`

And updated the image URLs for existing posts using the PHPmyAdmin search replace tool, eg, all

- `mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/` URLs to
- `cdn.mysite.com/media/`

I also updated the wp-options table, upload path and upload url path fields as below:

- **upload path**  `/myserverroot/user/cdn/media`
- **upload url path** `https://cdn.mysite.com/media/`

However when I refresh the webpages I see all media is missing, and when I check the IMG tag HTML I see the src URL is prepended by the website's base URL as below:

`img src="https:// mysite.com/https://cdn.mysite.com/media/2019/9/image.jpg"`

Any ideas on what the cause could be? Many thanks.

Comment: The constant of UPLOADS is relative to the ABSPATH, which is the absolute path to the WordPress directory. https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#moving-uploads-folder Have you thought of making a symlink that will connect the two?

Comment: Hi I'm not quite sure how to do that, my knowledge in the area is limited. However the one tip that i used was to ensure the line define('UPLOADS', 'https:// cdn.mysite.com/media'); is added before the line require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php' );

Comment: @JosuaMarcelC, remember that the [`UPLOADS`  constant](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/wp-config-php/#moving-uploads-folder) is **always relative to  `ABSPATH`**. However, using a value like `images.josuamarcelc.com` shouldn't cause the "i got this for all images "`josuamarcelc.com/https://images.josua...`" - so, are you sure you didn't actually add "https://" when you defined `UPLOADS`? Are you using WordPress v6.0 - if not, what version are you using? Have you tried deactivating all plugins and/or switching to a default theme like 2021? Did the same issue persist?

Comment: You could also try clearing your caches. And @tammix, what's the solution you ended up using back then?

Comment: @SallyCJ i still cannot remove the ABSPATH after clearing the cache

Comment: @JosuaMarcelC you should have posted your own question so that you could add more details like the code you used and more context, e.g. does the subdomain reside in `ABSPATH`, i.e. is `images.josuamarcelc.com` a subdirectory in the document root for the main domain. You also didn't answer my other questions, e.g. what's your WordPress version and did deactivating plugins help.

Comment: @SallyCJ sorry, my bad, my WP version is Current version: 6.0, i put 
define('UPLOADS', 'https://images.josuamarcelc.com'); on my wp-config.php before require_once ABSPATH,  but not working

Answer (score 0):

This will not work the way you are thinking. Wordpress will try to upload attachments (images, pdfs, etc) to your server using the `UPLOADS` constant, this path is a **file path**, local to the server.

---

If you wish to use a CDN you can [get a CDN service](https://wpbuffs.com/wordpress-cdn-plugins/) to do this (manage files and upload them remotely to their service) or possibly use a tool [like this to rewrite URLs](https://perfmatters.io/) on the fly.

I can't say how good [this plugin is but](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-file-upload/) seems like this could do what you are looking for, upload your attachments to another (remote) server.

Comment: i wish to put on my own same server, but only the url different url with subdomain

Answer (score 0):

To change the path to the media file, you can change the path via hook or directly in the database. However, a solid path with WordPress technic is a simple plugin that fire the hook and change the path of the media files.

The entries are in the table `_options`, entries `upload_path` and `upload_url_path`. You can set in the database a new path or use the following code snippet to change them with the help of the hooks.

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_upload_path', function( $upload_path ) {
    return '/path/to/static';
});

add_filter( 'pre_option_upload_url_path', function( $upload_url_path ) {
    return 'http://static.example.org';
});
```

Existing content should search, replace so that all existing media files have the right path inside the content of each post/page in the database. You will find all content, include URLs/Paths to the media files in the table `_posts`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a demo website first.

Leave the `upload_path` empty.

Change `upload_url_path` to your subdomain.

In phpmyadmin use the code below to update already uploaded images attached in posts. Change wp_posts with your database prefix and you domain names

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'https://mydemodomain.gr/wp-content/uploads/', 'https://images.mydemodomain.gr/uploads/');
```

And lastly in htaccess

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ https://images.mydemodomain.gr/$1
```